# BIBO stable system

Tags: math-software, signal-processing, control-theory

I would like to ask if this system is Bounded Input Bounded Output stable :

$$y[n] = r^nx[n],\quad r\in \mathbb{R}$$

And why?
I think this system is stable because

$$| x[n] |  ≤  B,\quad B < \infty\Rightarrow
|y[n] |=| r^nx[n]| \le |r^n| |x[n]|\le  B   < \infty$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is not BIBO stable because $r^n$ is not bounded for $|r|>1$.